# what is the difference between the using of viewData dictionary and viewData.Model in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need your help.

please could anyone explain me what is the difference between the using of viewData dictionary and viewData.Model in asp.net mvc.

for example I can write

```
viewData["list"] = list;
```

and I can write

```
viewData.Model = list;
```

so what is the difference between them and when to use each one;

explanation with an example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ViewData.Model is just another way to pass a model object from the controller's action to the view.  You can use this method to ensure that your view's model will be strongly-typed, and can then reference your object using "@Model" within the View.

```
@Model.SomeProperty
```

Alternatively (and preferably), you could just pass your model object from action to view using the "return View(t);" where t = the object.

```
return View(myObject);
```

Lastly, using

```
ViewData.["someName"] = someObject
```

would be a loosely-typed object, and you couldn't reference your object using @Model from the View.  Instead, you'd have to cast the ViewData as a model-type within your View to be able to reference it.  Example:

```
// in the action:
ViewData["obj"] = someObject;

// in the view:
var objData = ViewData["obj"] as MyObjectClass

// referencing a property of the object:
@objData.SomeProperty
```

So you can see there's a bit extra work involved when you choose this method.  Personally, I don't use ViewData very often... ViewBag makes more sense to me when I need to send something to the View that isn't included as part of the viewmodel.